# problem with the installing NS-3

Tags: python

I am trying to install NS-3 on my Ubuntu 16.04 and I have a strange problem. I installed all the prerequisites for ns3 and its time to install ns3 itself. I'm installing it through the bake,(https://www.nsnam.org/wiki/Installation#Installation_with_Bake) and when I execute this command (bake.py check) the answer I got is all good and OK. But when I get to this command (bake.py show) it seems that I did not install some prerequisites. like :pygraphviz.   then I get back and installed the pygraphviz again and I checked that the answer is (python-pygraphviz is already the newest version (1.3.1-0ubuntu2).) so what should I do????

Comment: It's probably looking for *newer* `pygraphvis` or Python 3 ones - python3 libraries are typically provided by `python3-` packages, so you may need `python3-pygraphviz`

Comment: @ThomasWard I did it. but it's not working.

Comment: I tried to istall Ns3 through the Tarball. I could download it and the extract it but when I get to this command (./build.py) ,(https://www.nsnam.org/wiki/Installation#Building_ns-3_with_build.py) the answer I get is wrong.It does not work.

Comment: I'm sorry, but was wrong with installing `ns3` [package from repository](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&exact=1&searchon=names&keywords=ns3)?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with Ubuntu 20.04 and ns 3.33.

I solved this by manually editing `bakefile.xml`.

It seems that `Bake.py` uses this file as its input to determine which packages to seek and, more to the point, which files in the packages to use as indicators of presence of the packages.

The problematic entry was:

```
<attribute - 'dependency_test' name="dependency_test" value="(_gv.so or _graphviz.so or _graphviz.x86_64-linux-gnu.so)"
```

I used `apt-file list python3-pygraphviz` to search for the referenced `.so` files but only found `_graphviz.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so`.

Therefore, I changed the above line in the XML file, to:

```
<attribute - 'dependency_test' name="dependency_test" value="(_gv.so or _graphviz.so or _graphviz.x86_64-linux-gnu.so or _graphviz.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so)"
```

This fixed the problem for me.